# jquery table parsing not working

Tags: jquery

I am having difficulty understanding why this jquery (shown below) to create a table is not working.   All the data values are numerically correct.  The problem is that in the view, I see :

A Table header that is created correctly
and then a single row (horizontal) where all rows are printed next to each other as in:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
1    2    4    5    5    6   7   8   9   10  11  12   13 14  15
```

when it should be

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 
1    2    4    5    5    
6    7    8    9   10
11  12   13   14   15
```

Any hint of what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.   I've been looking at the code for hours.   I know I am missing something.

```
            if (jsonData.length > 0) {
            $('#grid2R').empty();
            $('#grid2R').append("RESETS <br />");
            $('#grid2R').append('<table id="grid-resets" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">');
            $('#grid2R').append('<thead>'
                + '<tr>'
                + '<th data-column-id="col1" data-order="desc">col1</th>'
                + '<th data-column-id="col2">col2</th>'
                + '<th data-column-id="col3" >col3</th>'
                + '<th data-column-id="col4">col4</th>'
                + '<th data-column-id="col5">col5</th>'
                + '</tr>'
                + '</thead>');

            for (i = 0; i < resets.length; i++) {
                var col1Value= jsonData[i].col1Value;
                var col2Value= jsonData[i].col2Value;
                var col3Value= jsonData[i].col3Value;
                var col4Value= jsonData[i].col4Value;
                var col5Value= jsonData[i].col5Value;
                if (i == 0) {
                    $('#grid2R').append('<tbody>');
                }
                $('#grid2R').append(
                    + '<tr>'
                    + '<td class="aTD">' + col1Value+ '</td>'
                    + '<td class="aTD">' + col2Value+ '</td>'
                    + '<td class="aTD">' + col3Value+ '</td>'
                    + '<td class="aTD">' + col4Value+ '</td>'
                    + '<td class="aTD">' + col5Value+ '</td>'
                    + '</tr>');
                if (i == resets.length - 1) {
                    $('#grid2R').append('</tbody></table>');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#grid2R').empty();
            $('#grid2R').append("No Resets we found");
        }
    });
    $("#imgSpinner1").hide();
```

Comment: jQuery `.append()` is not simply a string concatenation: `$('#grid2R').append('</tbody></table>');` is invalid, for example. You append a tbody within `#grid2R`, and insert HTML into it by using `.html()`, `appendTo` or `append()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial `+ "<tr>"` tries to evaluate `"<tr>"` as a number, resulting in `NaN`, so you don't get the rows you want.

Additionally, you need only add the `tbody` once, then append to *that*. Don't try and append the closing `</tbody>` or `</table>`:

```
var tb = $("<tbody>").appendTo( $('#grid2R') );

for (i = 0; i < resets.length; i++) {
  var col1Value= jsonData[i].col1Value;
  var col2Value= jsonData[i].col2Value;
  var col3Value= jsonData[i].col3Value;
  var col4Value= jsonData[i].col4Value;
  var col5Value= jsonData[i].col5Value;

  tb.append(
      '<tr>'
      + '<td class="aTD">' + col1Value+ '</td>'
      + '<td class="aTD">' + col2Value+ '</td>'
      + '<td class="aTD">' + col3Value+ '</td>'
      + '<td class="aTD">' + col4Value+ '</td>'
      + '<td class="aTD">' + col5Value+ '</td>'
      + '</tr>');
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the `+ '<tr>'`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is used to append one or more **elements**, not HTML code.

Try something more like this:

```
// create and append the tbody element
var tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo( '#grid2R' );

for (i = 0; i < resets.length; i++) {
    var col1Value= jsonData[i].col1Value;
    var col2Value= jsonData[i].col2Value;
    var col3Value= jsonData[i].col3Value;
    var col4Value= jsonData[i].col4Value;
    var col5Value= jsonData[i].col5Value;

    // append rows to the tbody element
    tbody.append(
        '<tr>'
        + '<td class="aTD">' + col1Value+ '</td>'
        + '<td class="aTD">' + col2Value+ '</td>'
        + '<td class="aTD">' + col3Value+ '</td>'
        + '<td class="aTD">' + col4Value+ '</td>'
        + '<td class="aTD">' + col5Value+ '</td>'
        + '</tr>');
}
```

I'll also point out that every time you call `$('`*`some selector`*`')` you are forcing jQuery to scan the entire document all over again. It's much better to simply store the results of your first query and the reuse it, like so:

```
var grid2R = $('#grid2R');
grid2R.empty();
grid2R.append('<table id="grid-resets" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">');
```

Comment: `var tbody = $('#grid2R').append('<tbody>');` sets `tbody` to the `#grid2R` element, not the appended element.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 5 columns then you need a counter in your loop (or a second loop)

Once you have reached 5 then you need to end the current table row and start a new one